# convert yuv420p raw data to image opencv

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg

I have raw data from rtmp server with pixel format yuv420p

I use pipe to read data. But I don't know how to decode raw data to image.

```
command = ['ffmpeg']
command.extend(["-loglevel", "fatal", "-i", 'rtmp://localhost/live/stream', "-f", "flv", "-pix_fmt" , 'yuv420p', '-vcodec', 'h264', "-"])
self.process = subprocess.Popen(command, stderr=subprocess.PIPE ,stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
self.output = self.process.stdout
self.fs = width*height*3 // 2
while True:
    data = self.output.read(self.fs)
```

I have try decode like this [enter link description here](https://gist.github.com/eruffaldi/1226191b0dd50737e74dafc0ec73caad)

But result is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkxlD.jpg)

Can anyone help me with this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no expert on `ffmpeg`, so I will defer to anybody who knows better and delete my answer if it proves incorrect.

As far as I can see, you have an RTMP stream that you want to ingest into OpenCV. OpenCV uses Numpy arrays with BGR ordering to store images - and video frames obviously, which are just lots of images one after the other. So, I would suggest you ask `ffmpeg` to convert the Flash video stream to exactly what OpenCV wants:

```
ffmpeg <RTMP INPUT STUFF> -pix_fmt bgr24 -f rawvideo -
```

and then change this since it is now BGR888:

```
self.fs = width * height * 3
```

---

As I don't have an RTMP source available, I generated a test stream like this:

```
# Generate raw video stream to read into OpenCV    
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc=duration=10:size=640x480:rate=30 -pixel_format rgb24 -f rawvideo -
```

And then I piped that into Python with:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc=duration=10:size=640x480:rate=30 -pixel_format rgb24 -f rawvideo - | ./PlayRawVideo
```

The Python program `PlayRawVideo` looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import cv2
import sys

# Set width and height
w, h = 640, 480

while True:
    data = sys.stdin.buffer.read(w * h *3)
    if len(data) == 0:
        break
    frame = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.uint8).reshape((h, w, 3))
    cv2.imshow("Stream", frame)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Note that I had to use `sys.stdin.buffer.read()` to get raw binary data.

[image]

Comment: turn out i have input wrong option -f in ffmpeg command. Thanks for your answer